# Custom attributes on EF code-first models

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Currently using EF 6 in a new project. I've been using EF for sometime now, so am pretty familiar with it - at the very least as the average user of it.

We are looking to split storage of data between SQL (eventually Azure SQL) and Azure Table Storage.

The reason for the split is some of the data on an entity just isn't suitable for a relational database. For example, we have some clients that prefer contact's to have properties `A,B,C,D` and another client prefers to have `F,G,H,I,J,K,L` - so it would make more sense to store this part of the data in a NoSql solution so we're not constraining ourselves, rather than adding dozens of columns in a table to handle varying requirements on that model.

We're currently, in the new build, serializing/deserializing these sets of data which is ok, though not ideal. Especially given it can be expensive performing this task on every read/write.

So - that leads me to my question. (no code to show at this time)

I figured I would be able to decorate specific properties on some data models with a custom attribute, such as `[NoSqlStore]` and then react to these. I can, for example, override the `SaveChanges()` method in EF to save data to the appropriate table store should any property on the entity contain the attribute.

The hard part, at least what I'm struggling with at the moment, is how to handle reads from the database. I would, ideally, like to be able to listen for (or override) something in EF that is fired when data is being fetched. Is there such an event/method built into EF for this? I figure if i can intercept EF when it's populating my model I can then react to any attribute decoration.

Comment: I'm sure your situation is more complex than you suggest, but if not, simply having configurable properties is not really a good reason to choose NoSql, it's quite easy to do that in a relational model.  NoSql really shines if you have a boatload of data in a non-relational model, but if your data needs are small, you can simulate a key-value store relationally.

Comment: I've tried to make some of the info as simple as possible, so as to not detract away from the actual question. There is a good deal of data that doesn't follow typical relational database design. Splitting the data between sql & nosql would actually significantly increase both our systems performance and also a lot of the processes involved in fulfilling client requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF6 you can use the command interception mechanism where the interceptor is invoked each time the command is being executed. You can also modify results if needed (might be a bit cumbersome though). [This article](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interception) is a good starting point. Another way to go about it is to look at the [ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and populate properties that are not populated by EF in the handler for this event.

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look and it seems a good place to start. I've put together a quick and dirty class that is intercepting the commands. Any idea how I get to the model that the command is supposed to be running for? (make sense?)

Comment: I wonder if you should not just [Ignore] the properties you don't want. Otherwise it might be very hard to make it work (when working on http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/03/20/second-level-cache-for-ef-6-1/ I found that there is no way of correlating linq queries with Sql commands you see in the command interceptor and ended up using a wrapping provider. The difference is that I did not have to modify results and this is where it gets really tricky (if not impossible) to handle - especially for queries with .Includes/joins).

Comment: Yes, we could ignore some properties, which would ensure EF didn't do anything with them, though on those properties i need to populate them with data from NoSql. The property being ignored would likely be a complex object which could contain different properties depending on the client; hence wanting to store that in a noSql as it doesn't have to follow structure.

Comment: Then it might be easier than you think - subscribe to the `ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized(v=vs.110).aspx) and populate the properties not populated by EF there.

Comment: thats awesome, thanks. I'm subscribed to that event now - If you could also put that comment in the answer i'll gladly marked as answered. On a slight side-note - I'm having to do both of these as the ObjectMaterialized isn't fired when doing a projection.